# Inverse Laplace Transform - Some Confusion on Breaking into Component Functions (Find the solution y(t) )

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Been redoing the last part of the problem and not understanding the book solution.

Would appreciate clarification. Thanks.

## Given: $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{2dy}{dt}+26y=\delta _4\left(t\right)\:$ $ -> IC.\:y\left(0\right)=1,\:y'\left(0\right)=0$

Did:

1. apply$ :\ L[f(t)]\:$ to all $\ fcn(t)\:$
2. apply derivative rules for Laplace Transforms
3. get $:\ L[y(t)]\:$  in terms of $  \ fcn(s)\: $
4. complex $\lambda \:$ --> complete the square in the denominator of $  \ fcn(s)\: $ to generate a known form $ : \sin\left(\omega t\right)\:or\:cos\left(\omega t\right)\ $

### My basic $s $  domain expression  is Correct:

## $ \ Y(s) =  \frac{e^{-4s}}{\left(s+1\right)^2+5^2}\:+\:\frac{\left(s+2\right)}{\left(s+1\right)^2+5^2}\ $

### Book Solution: $\ y\left(t\right)=\:e^{-t}cos5t\:+\frac{1}{5}e^{-t}sin5t+\frac{1}{5}u_4\left(t\right)e^{-\left(t-4\right)}sin\left(5\left(t-4\right)\right) \ $

#### *My "simplified" s domain expression*

### $ \ Y\left(s\right)=\frac{1}{5}\cdot e^{-4s}\cdot \frac{5}{\left(s+1\right)^2+5^2}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot \left(s+2\right)\cdot \frac{5}{\left(s+1\right)^2+5^2} \ $

#### *My solution*

### $ \:y\left(t\right)=\:\delta _4\left(t\right)\cdot \frac{1}{5}e^{-t}\cdot sin\left(5t\right)+e^{2t}\cdot \frac{1}{5}\left(sin\left(5t\right)\right) \ $

#### Don't Understand:

- Where the heaviside function comes from.
- Why you can/have to split
  the $ \ s+2\  $ numerator function using partial fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that

$$\mathcal L^{-1}_t\left\{e^{-cs}F(s)\right\}=u_c(t)f(t-c)$$

$$\implies\mathcal L^{-1}_t\left\{\frac{e^{-4s}}{(s+1)^2+5^2}\right\}=u_4(t)f(t-4)$$

where $f(t)$ is the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)$. Also, recall that

$$\mathcal L^{-1}_t\left\{F(s-c)\right\}=e^{ct}f(t)$$

$$\implies\mathcal L^{-1}_t\left\{\frac1{(s+1)^2+5^2}\right\}=e^{-t}\mathcal L^{-1}_t\left\{\frac1{s^2+5^2}\right\}=\frac15e^{-t}\sin(5t)$$

Putting these together gives

$$\mathcal L^{-1}_t\left\{\frac{e^{-4s}}{(s+1)^2+5^2}\right\}=\frac15u_4(t)e^{-(t-4)}\sin(5(t-4))$$

---

On the other hand,

$$\frac{s+2}{(s+1)^2+5^2}=\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+5^2}+\frac1{(s+1)^2+5^2}$$

and you should recognize these as having the inverse transforms (using one of the properties mentioned above),

$$\mathcal L^{-1}_t\left\{\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+5^2}\right\}=e^{-t}\mathcal L^{-1}_t\left\{\frac s{s^2+5^2}\right\}=e^{-t}\cos(5t)$$

$$\mathcal L^{-1}_t\left\{\frac1{(s+1)^2+5^2}\right\}=e^{-t}\mathcal L^{-1}_t\left\{\frac1{s^2+5^2}\right\}=\frac15e^{-t}\sin(5t)$$

Comment: THANK YOU - very good description

Comment: Does the delta forcing induce a heaviside component in the solution have to do with something similar to Fourier theory - that a signal broad in time will be very restricted in space and vice versa? So a delta fcn of forcing must include a u_a(t) in the solution. And if the forcing includes a u_a(t) component, the solution function must include a delta(t) component?